# JavaScript: Unable to set logic for searching

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a movie website, where I m stuck on setting search filter for user as I want that if user click on particular genres so it display that particular genre movies but I was unable to set logic for this :-

here is JavaScript code :-

```
/jshint esversion:6

const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".option-container");

const optionList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

selected.addEventListener("click", clickable);

function clickable() {
  optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
}

optionList.forEach(o => {
  o.addEventListener("click", function() {
    selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
    optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
  });
});



// search bar

const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const books = document.getElementsByTagName('h4');
  Array.from(books).forEach(function(book) {
    const title = book.textContent;
    if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
      book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'flex';
    } else {
      book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none'
    }
  });
});




const allMovies = document.querySelector("#all");
allMovies.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll(".allMovie");
  all.forEach(function (a) {
    a.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});

const actionMovie = document.querySelector("#action");
actionMovie.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var movies = document.querySelectorAll(".allMovie");
  movies.forEach(function (f) {
    if (f.classList.contains("actionMovie")) {
      f.classList.toggle('active');
    }else {
      f.classList.toggle('inactive');
    }
  });
});

const dramaMovie = document.querySelector("#drama");
actionMovie.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var movies = document.querySelectorAll(".allMovie");
  movies.forEach(function (f) {
    if (f.classList.contains("dramaMovie")) {
      f.classList.toggle('active');
    }else {
      f.classList.toggle('inactive');
    }
  });
});
```

Html code:

```
  <section class="search-section">
    <div class="select-box">

      <div class="option-container">
        <div class="option" id="all">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" name="category" value="All">
          <label for="all">All</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option" id="action">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" name="category" title="actionmovie" value="Action">
          <label for="action">Action</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option" id="Drama">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="drama" name="category" value="Drama">
          <label for="drama">Drama</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option" id="Sci-fi">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="sci-fi" name="category" value="Sci-fi">
          <label for="sci-fi">Sci-fi</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="selected">
        <h2>Genre</h2>

      </div>


    </div>

      <form class="search-box" id="search-books" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" name="searchBox" placeholder="seach here" class="form-control">
      </form>

  </section>

  <section class="Movies-section">
    <div class="size allMovie actionMovie"><img src="images/movies/bat-man.jpg" alt="Batman">
      <div class="Movie-detail">
        <h4>Dark Knight</h4>
        <p>action</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="size allMovie actionMovie"><img src="images/movies/blood-shot.jpg" alt="Blood shot">
      <div class="Movie-detail">
        <h4>Bloodshot</h4>
        <p>action</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="size allMovie dramaMovie"><img src="images/movies/call.jpg" alt="call">
      <div class="Movie-detail">
        <h4>Call</h4>
        <p>drama</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="size allMovie actionMovie"><img src="images/movies/captain-marvel.png" alt="captain marvel">
      <div class="Movie-detail">
        <h4>Captain marvel</h4>
        <p>action/sci-fi</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="size allMovie actionMovie"><img src="images/movies/end-game.jpg" alt="avenger end game">
      <div class="Movie-detail">
        <h4>Avengers end game</h4>
        <p>action/sci-fi</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="size allMovie"><img src="images/movies/hunter-killer.jpg" alt="hunter Killer">
      <div class="Movie-detail">
        <h4>Hunter killer</h4>
        <p>Thriller</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="size allMovie"><img src="images/movies/insidious.jpg" alt="insidious">
      <div class="Movie-detail">
        <h4>Insidious</h4>
        <p>Horror/Thriller</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="size allMovie dramaMovie"><img src="images/movies/love-roise.jpg" alt="love roise">
      <div class="Movie-detail">
        <h4>Love roise</h4>
        <p>drama/romance</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    

  </section>

  <footer>
    <a href="#" class="logo"><span>365</span></a>
    <p>Powered by 365 Entertainment Portal 2021. All rights Reserved.</p>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

By above logic I m only able to filter genre "all movie" "action movie" but when I try to search after "action" it doesn't work, and also not for "drama movies".

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML too.

Comment: Why not just target the relevant classes directly: `document.querySelectorAll('.dramaMovie')`?

Comment: @Jamiec I have added html code.

Comment: @Andy I didn't get you. Can you please write code for it.